# Android Push Notification - Google Play

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Push Notification into my android App using GCM. It is working fine. Now I am going to upload my app to Google Play. Do I need to change anything on my push notification settings for uploading to Google Play?

Comment: Are you using App Engine or your own server?

Comment: Have nothing to do if they use App Engine or own Server.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to change nothing. If it's working on your testing area it will work in production (Google Play) too...

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented [Urban Airship Push Notification](http://urbanairship.com/) then you have to make your production flag `true` and change code like this:

```
public static final boolean URBAN_AIRSHIP_IN_PRODUCTION = true;
public static final boolean URBAN_AIRSHIP_RICH_PUSH_ENABLED = false;
```